Check that given line integral over a closed contour equals to zero
I'm supposed to check that $\int_{C}f(xy)(ydx+xdy)$ equals to zero over a closed contour.
My take on this is following:
Let $P(x,y)=yf(xy)$, and $Q(x,y)=xf(xy)$.
Now I calculate $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$ and if they are equal to each other then the line integral is path independent and consequently it equals to zero over a closed path.
Using product and chain rule I get:
$\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}=f(xy)+xy\frac{\partial f(xy)}{\partial x}$, $\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=f(xy)+xy\frac{\partial f(xy)}{\partial y}$
So, depending on $f$ they may or may not be equal. Am I missing something here or is there another way to show that this integral equals to zero? Thanks for any and all help.

Note that the function $f$ is univariate, hence $\partial_xf = \partial_yf = f'$.

@Abezhiko +1. Oh those symbols!

Thank you @Abezhiko. It so obvious now.
